# Setting Nested Object Values from AngularJS Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I am trying to set a value of a nested object from my Angular Controller but I keep getting the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'field0' of undefined
```

The code in my Controller is:

```
$scope.obj = $scope.obj || {};

$scope.autosave = function(){
    $window.sessionStorage.setItem("experienceOne", $scope.obj.experience.field0);
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Im sure its something small but I can't seem figure it out. How can I set the value in a nested object. Just for reference the object structure is like this:

```
obj{
     name:"",
     experience:{
        field0:"",
        field1:"",
        field2:""
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't set `experience` property in default branch. So `obj.experience.something` throws because `experience` is undefined. It should be

```
$scope.obj = $scope.obj || {experience: {}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does the above set `experience` as a nested object in `obj`? I always thought by using the dot notation like so `obj.something.somethingElse` this works when I set values from the front-end like so `<input type=text ng-model=obj.experience.field0>` but does not work when I try to do the same from my controller.

Comment: `ng-model` will create all the nested structure for you. [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/SybR2RAEpdpiRy9cpLba?p=preview) But you have a code that might run before model controller does its magic.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a property of a nested object with something like this:

```
obj.experience.field03 = "aa";
```